# Why does my Google Analytics API query return exactly 1.000.000 rows?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am fetching GA event data with following query:

```
body = {
            'reportRequests': [
                {
                    'viewId': 'xxxxx',
                    'dateRanges': [
                        {
                            'startDate': '2017-01-01',
                            'endDate': '2020-12-31'
                        }
                    ],
                    'metrics': [
                        {'expression': 'ga:itemRevenue'},
                        {'expression': 'ga:totalEvents'},
                    ],
                    'dimensions': [
                        {"name": "ga:clientId"},
                        {"name": "ga:pagePath"},
                        {"name": "ga:dateHourMinute"},
                        {"name": "ga:sessionDurationBucket"},
                        {"name": "ga:eventAction"},
                        {"name": "ga:source"},
                        {"name": "ga:sessionCount"},
                        {"name": "ga:landingPagePath"},
                        {"name": "ga:pageDepth"},
                    ],
                    'orderBys': [{"fieldName": "ga:dateHourMinute", "sortOrder": "ASCENDING"}],
                    'pageSize': 5000,
                }]
        }
```

I queried the total number of events through the API = 2.640.221 events with following query

```
payload = {
            'reportRequests': [
                {
                    'viewId': xxxxx,
                    'dateRanges': [
                        {
                            'startDate': '2017-01-01',
                            'endDate': '2020-12-31'
                        }
                    ],
                    'metrics': [
                        {'expression': 'ga:totalEvents'},
                    ],
                }
            ]
        }
```

and compared it to what I see in GA, the numbers are identical:

[image]

The result of my 1st query suprised me bit: 1.000.000 records, the start/end dates are exactly my boundaries.

[image]

Did I run into any limits? I definitely didn't submit 10.000 queries in the current month.
How does it come that the first record is from short after 2017-01-01 midnight and last one right on 2020-12-31 23:47

Comment: Thats the limit no query will return more then 1.000.000 records.  Your probably getting hit pretty hard by sampling to have a limit of that anyway.

Comment: @DaImTo Sorry, don’t understand what you mean. Can I avoid it by querying in smaller portions?